# How to call a function from a AngularJS directive with checkbox, when it is checked?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Recently I have implemented a directive which uses a checkbox customized with css. I need to call a function from a scope when the value of checkbox is checked. I've got something working with `ng-click` but this is not what I am searching for.

I looked into `ng-true-value`, but it expects a value, not a function I can invoke. Is there any way to solve this so the function can be called only when checkbox is active? This is the directive definition:

```
{
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    require: ['^ngModel'],
    scope:{ 
            isChecked: '=?', 
            secondFunction: '&'
          },
    template: function (elem, attr){
      var a= '<label class="switch"'+attr.class+'><input type="checkbox" ng-class="{checked: isChecked}"><i></i></label>';
      return a;    
    }, 
}
```

[Plunk with a directive](https://plnkr.co/edit/NkdaXLWFKT5pDaodMm5F?p=preview)

Comment: you could look at $scope.watch $watch(watchExpression, listener, [objectEquality]);

Registers a listener callback to be executed whenever the watchExpression changes.

The watchExpression is called on every call to $digest() and should return the value that will be watched. (watchExpression should not change its value when executed multiple times with the same input because it may be executed multiple times by $digest().

Comment: Depending on your needs, you can use `ng-change` or a simple `$watch` to control your logic.  This can happen in the link function (since you have access to the scope), but I'd recommend just using a controller for the directive instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, for replies and for edit. I used, as you suggested a $watch. There is still a question is there any way to do achieve this, with any function which I put on scope, so the directive can be universal? Like ng-click for instance.

Answer (score 0):

use `ng-change = 'functionName()'` on chechkbox

[Reference:](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

Answer (score 0):

you can use **ng-model** and **watch** function to perform logics on checking checkboxes

```
$scope.$watch('modelName', function() {
    // do something here

});
```